# SyntaxError: invalid syntax WHILE INSTALLING GLOB2

Tags: installation, module, package, libraries

Here is the command:

```
>>> pip install glob2
```

Here is the Output Message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install glob2
        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

U should try install glob not in python but from command prompt.
open command prompt with admin privileges and then type the command,

```
pip install glob2
```

it should work